# Getting blank dropdown value even after using ng-selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using ng-selected to get the selected value from a dropdown. But instead it's showing as blank.

I have tried the following code:

```
<div>
   <select id="user_org" ng-model="selectedorg.allValue" ng-change="qrochange(this)" material-select watch required >
           <option ng-selected='{{selectedorg.allValue == user.user_org}}' ng-repeat="user in orgowners | unique:'user_org'" value="{{user.id}},{{user.user_org_quota}}">{{user.user_org}}</option>
   </select>
   <label for="user_org">Organization</label>
</div>
```

Controller.js:

```
var orgowners = Restangular.one("users/" + user_id + "/list");
            orgowners.getList().then(function(projects) {
                $scope.orgowners = projects;
                 var parent_index = $scope.findIndexByKeyValue($scope.orgowners,'id',$scope.id);
                    $scope.selectedorg= $scope.orgowners[parent_index];
                    $scope.selectedorg.allValue = $scope.selectedorg.id+','+$scope.selectedorg.user_org_quota;
                    $scope.qro = $scope.selectedorg.user_org_quota;
            })

        $scope.qrochange = function(event) {
                id = event.selectedorg.allValue;
                var quota_res = id.split(',')[1];
                $scope.qro = quota_res;
                $scope.user_org_quota = parseInt(quota_res);
            }
```

How do I get the selected value?

Answer (score 0):

ng-model should give the selected value.

An easier way to render the dropdown is using ng-options. Something like:

```
<select ng-model="selectedorg" ng-options="user.user_org for user in orgowners | unique:'user_org'">
```

See also: [angularjs ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. selectedorg should have the selected item.

Comment: I have gone through the article and tried various possibilities; still didn't find the solution.

Comment: A working sample: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CZVmEPqVQpdnJPGOaPyz)